# Difference between command line argument and giving an input command

Tags: perl

What is the difference between `@ARGV` and asking the user for input?

```
$num = $ARGV[0];
```

and

```
$_ = <STDIN>;
```

Either way a user has to put an input isn't it?

How are they different?

Answer (score 2):

They don't address the same needs for the program.

A command-line argument is known by the program at the moment it starts. Getting a input from a user through stdin can be done at any moment of the execution of the program. What the user inputs could depend on what the program had output so far.

And command line arguments are usually short inputs whereas through stdin you can get any content, for example if a user redirects the standard input from a file.

Usually, command-line arguments are *options* for the program whereas sandard input are *data* to be processed. Sometimes, you can use one or the other and do the same thing, sometimes not.